# How to fix code blocks in list syntax highlighting of Markdown files in Codium?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, markdown, vscodium

I am using Codium and VSCode to edit Markdown files.

The syntax highlighting breaks inside of code-blocks under an item:

---

````
Some list with codeblocks:

- dikfree
  ```sh
  # Interesting comment
  df -h
  ```
- disk usage
  ```sh
  # Disk usage of /var
  du -BM --max-depth=1 /var
  ```
````

---

Is there anything I can do to help Codium/VSCode to recognize the code blocks? The only reason I don't attempt to install an extension that works well with markdown, is that I can't install any extensions.

Here is how I expect it to look like:

[image: No syntax highlighting]

Here is how it actually looks like:

[image: Expected syntax highlighting]

Comment: I tried to clean up your post, but the markdown examples seem to to be interfering with the actual markdown on the site for this question.

Comment: thanks, but you did manage to put the markdown-code between two lines. That's an improvement right there!

Comment: Could you show the problem on a screenshot as I'm not following what exactly breaks? And why can't you install extensions?

Comment: Ok, so like I thought. That's default behavior of VSCode and you can't do anything about it, apart from installing an extension that maybe could fix it. Since you wrote you can't install any and didn't explain why, the only possible recommendation here is to report a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180246) of Visual Studio Code. The developers have stated it's an [upstream issue](https://github.com/textmate/markdown.tmbundle/issues/55) of TextMate Markdown bundle, so they're waiting for that to get fixed:

> It looks like this is an issue with the markdown grammar. I've copied the issue to [textmate/markdown.tmbundle#55](https://github.com/textmate/markdown.tmbundle/issues/55), which is the repo that we get our markdown syntax highlighting grammar from.

There is definitely no way to get around it if you can't install extensions. With extension it might be possible to override the default syntax highlighting for Markdown, but I doubt an up-to-date extension for that exists when it's an in-built functionality.

Also note that removing the code block start/end indents fixes the issue:

````markdown
Some list with codeblocks:

- diskfree
```sh
  # Interesting comment
  df -h
```
````